# C++ HOW can this out-of-range access inside struct go wrong?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, compiler-optimization, undefined-behavior

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

struct TradeMsg {
  int64_t timestamp; // 0->7
  char exchange; // 8
  char symbol[17]; // 9->25
  char sale_condition[4]; // 26 -> 29
  char source_of_trade; // 30
  uint8_t trade_correction;  // 31
  int64_t trade_volume; // 32->39
  int64_t trade_price; // 40->47
};
static_assert(sizeof(TradeMsg) == 48);

char buffer[1000000];

template<class T, size_t N=1>
int someFunc(char* buffer, T* output, int& cursor) {
    // read + process data from buffer. Return data in output. Set cursor to the last byte read + 1.
    return cursor + (rand() % 20) + 1; // dummy code
}

void parseData(TradeMsg* msg) {
    int cursor = 0;
    cursor = someFunc<int64_t>(buffer, &msg->timestamp, cursor);
    cursor = someFunc<char>(buffer, &msg->exchange, cursor);
    
    cursor++;
    int i = 0;
    // i is GUARANTEED to be <= 17 after this loop,
    // edit: the input data in buffer[] guarantee that fact.
    while (buffer[cursor + i] != ',') {
        msg->symbol[i] = buffer[cursor + i];
        i++;
    }
    msg->symbol[i] = '\n'; // might access symbol[17].
    cursor = cursor + i + 1;
            
    for (i=0; i<4; i++) msg->sale_condition[i] = buffer[cursor + i];
    cursor += 5;
    
    //cursor = someFunc...
}

int main()
{
    TradeMsg a;
    a.symbol[17] = '\0';

    return 0;
}
```

I have this struct that is guaranteed to have predictable size. In the code, there is a case where the program tries to assign value to an array element past its size `msg->symbol[17]` = ... .

However, in that case, the assignment does not cause any harm as long as:

1. It is done before the next struct members (sale_condition) are assigned (no unexpected code reordering).
2. It does not modifies any previous members (timestamp, exchange).
3. It does not access any memory outside the struct.

I read that this is undefined behavior. But what kind of compiler optimization/code generation can make this go wrong? `symbol[17]` is pretty deep inside the middle of the struct, so I don't see how can the compiler generates an access outside it. Assume that platform is x86-64 only

Comment: Trying to predict when undefined behavior is okay is a fools errand. Change the code so it doesn't happen.

Comment: It can be done safely by if (i < sizeof(msg->symbol)) then ... ; but I just wonder about HOW a compiler can mess this code up

Comment: I don’t have a definitive answer here, but the question isn’t always about optimization or what could go wrong. It can be a question of “what would it cost to guarantee this as part of the standard”. You also have to keep in mind the standards apply to many systems beyond x86 that can be very different especially with respect to memory.

Comment: I suggest that you read this article about undefined behavior: [Undefined behavior can result in time travel (among other things, but time travel is the funkiest)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633). This should help you understand that it is never safe to rely on any kind of undefined behavior.

Comment: Heck, fails in debug mode on visual studio (out of bounds)

Comment: Each of your numerous assumptions can cause of potential problems.  You assume struct members are assigned in the same order as your code implies, but compilers reorder operations routinely, to improve against various metrics - and in the presence of undefined or even unspecified behaviour - such reorderings can have counter-intuitive effects. You have a comment "i is GUARANTEED to be <= 17 after this loop" but `i` depends on contents of `buffer` and your code offers no guarantees about content of `buffer`.  You assume x86-64 - but what prevents the code being compiled for another platform?

Comment: @Peter struct members are guaranteed to be in declaration order, for a *standard-layout* struct (which this is)

Comment: @M.M   I did not imply, in any way, that struct members can be ordered differently.  I mentioned order of operations (about which the OP is making a pretty big assumption).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel okay that was a good read. Thanks

Comment: Basically, some compilers treat (some kinds of) undefined behaviour as `#pragma unreachable` and aggressively optimise away large swathes of your code based on that; other compilers treat (similar kinds of) undefined behaviour as a run-time error. One is more efficient, the other more helpful. Both are strictly speaking correct. You can argue which is better, mostly based on what you mean by "better" (and people do)...

Comment: @JiříBaum: And of course, in situations where transitively applying parts of the Standard and  platform's documentation would mean there was only one way a construct could work, many implementations would, by design, behave in that way without regard for whether the Standard would *also* categorize the action as invoking UB.

Comment: Indeed, that's one philosophy of compiler design

Comment: Another philosophy aims to produce the smallest and/or fastest compiled program that's technically correct, no matter how counterintuitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Various folks have pointed out debug-mode checks that will fire on access outside the bounds of an array member of a struct, with options like `gcc -fsanitize=undefined`.  Separate from that, it's also legal for a compiler to use the assumption of non-overlap between member accesses to reorder two assignments which actually *do* alias:

[@Peter in comments points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70514670/c-how-can-this-out-of-range-access-inside-struct-go-wrong#comment124649054_70514670) that the compiler is allowed to assume that accesses to `msg->symbol[i]` don't affect other struct members, and potentially delay `msg->symbol[i] = '\n';` until after the loop that writes `msg->sale_condition[i]`.  (i.e. sink that store to the bottom of the function).

There isn't a good reason you'd *expect* a compiler to want to do that in this function alone, but perhaps after inlining into some caller that also stored something there, it could be relevant.  Or just because it's a DeathStation 9000 that exists in this thought experiment to break your code.

---

#### You could write this safely, although GCC compiles that worse

Since `char*` is allowed to alias any other object, you could offset a `char*` relative to the start of the whole struct, rather than to the start of the member array.  Use `offsetof` to find the right start point like this:

```
#include <cstddef>

    ...
    ((char*)msg + offsetof(TradeMsg, symbol))[i] = '\n'; // might access symbol[17].
```

That's exactly equivalent to `*((char*)msg + offsetof(...) + i) = '\n';` by definition of C++'s `[]` operator, even though it lets you use `[i]` to index relative to the same position.

However, **that does compile to less efficient asm with GCC11.2 -O2.**  ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEgKykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAzAmkAA6oCoRODB7evgGp6ZkCoeFRLLHxSbaY9o4CQgRMxAQ5Pn5cgXaYDlkNTQQlkTFxickKjc2teR22EwNhQ%2BUjSQCUtqhexMjsHOYJYcjeWADUJgluTuPEmKxn2CYaAIJ7B0eYp%2BfEhuioLHcPzzM%2BwYhy8JzObmQ43QWCo/yeXgyRmOzDYChSTG2x2hZysTwBVy8DmOABUvlgALIKYCnADseMex2OYQIADZJAB9AjHRxoxosFK444AemFxw0AFo7rSAUzkAgmsdMKp5YZgJghaLjgAOWXHVXEbEAT3KnhM/gsXBl/gAIpqxQBOKUJbBmfx6g3YsSYDloBj4OoMc0WSTmu0JCwisVmVnHZ3YY5mB0ehWGhQbLY%2B1BULnkjURqPHBIaPVeFnark8vO%2BkjXHoCIWFhJcPUs9mVgjVgBunh8%2BcjWoSZnjCWTTyZbc53M7TCwHJSxDw23tx0kkrukhl%2BNp4YZ4yYjmQHKYCiUzQgGQAXphsxAybPMFTgCsPuGbavtStcQCAZ7ol4qCoOJgy4DQwPAsNv3xJ4CEwAUDFgiFDhPBRSVIbE8GvSsIjOG0WxdAEWWxX5MAAMS8EEIANAAqY5/0AuJ0JJWiNgIFIvAIdCWXMWNkE2dNiBfEx6T1JktWuWdTksY4F1QbZT2OdADyYY4qGIX46IAoDiAAOmOAAlTACE2BhFOU5lTNY9iCD0oQjP1fiSB5VAeQQd4DHGOijVg44JPQKTIy4HTRN8oyTIc4gBIC44IC%2Bf0ICEt1Ew0RLApXdAfBYI19QwDVtztaDHh7PB/IxSLMBtZS7zzJ9aJYakhJE8cmQs7k%2BMipzcPFKDGRa9qoq69M2HIkEIUnLk7ggejtPQnj6uAeNeUwfcBXQ/qSC/CMQvWw1BpIkbTHOA1JumxipNZeb42VVUjEwNbHMEnqWtOZq5Qe6wPq216oyvH1uTwV9uq%2B3qJ0EZlAZLYHnq1AG8FQgBxORHn0x4IhJbBsHfIg6PeCEuqtY4mCoWDDQIBA4eOWhUFQFJSBCrVMADEBXPeMJrLMxoLM0hjiGDMNjmALwmkMWD3jJg9VMxGyQoAd3J%2BgYtO3mLR26K8H5sAwC6sBeB1xqGWe57LruBQTWiM0LXV21AaV4NVesZlIKhw2Jw%2Bywnpa4SCsBfYqFhY45AsDkADVsH0oQAEkAHkcO%2B42XVN01aGDK33213Z/DcBgdZXFg8GABBuUxeTUMT83k4tK0w2C/EgRqJQQqgGiVnm6LsyoJQiCoaqHyfdCy88FYv0t/n0/NLOc4LLU84LovkBL40k5A60bRrn3XDwOFvvthJ33t6SAYd/CDZdw2Qv4Q0ICI9Xd8hyMb7cUMC3V93LBfePsAUb0a39IogxH62XVbYqwemrJ2J83odV2u7Xexx3TOyZPTYUO93xDTIhRZAOksE/h3D%2BJ4REWBMDCAlHBEDSQ1WpITD2TImA6QHhXS0K9AY50zhoSeDIQrXGMsQUyd8cE2g4GsWgnB/C8D8BwLQpBUCcDcG7SM6ZNhYj2DwUgBBNCCLWG5B88QEqkAANaJFpDpfwDoNCsjdP4bUQ4zBAg0IEYRHBJBiPUVIzgvAFAgA0Ko9Raw4CwCQGgAUdBGIUCor8FIwT4jAC4FwMwfA6Akw8VNFx0QwhNCNJwFRgS2CCCjgwWgGSJG8CwIQow4gimkHwHWRwXZlouOVN0DiOwVEshqC42geBohfGIEaDwWAXGdjwCwTJgi%2BAGGAAoYOeBMAyyjikRgIyZCCBEN6CQ0h%2BCCEUCodQFTdBxIMEYFAcj9CdI8ZANYNNAweI4BKG0gcQ5h0jjHOMUczBxkIVsBAuEFQKBljUWg7iajdEDC4f0Uw/C0iCP6QYZQKggEkHEtIGRAzgpAJCpFf8YXDHiAi6otRehzFRZCro9YGB9GaFipYOK4n7kmL2PIxK5iUrhQitYCjMx6E7JgZpoyHGiNIOIyR0iOCqG1KyCU7IBbz2ODEnSbyICyNfjYY4uBCCdSBFwdCHggn0GgUOFYvA1FFKHqQLRWAdFrAMUOHSDoHS0jAgkfw/haSsi4NqbU9jOBOIFS44V7jPHeONaQPxiAUDhMieQSggSIm6pANE2J8TaCJMoNEFJaSemLOyYwAgeSCkuJKWqcpkiqnArwLU65kiGl8Vgos1pDjJEdK6ekvpOxJGDOGdwUZVBxmTOmbM%2BZ4iVEbOEKIcQUglnyCUGoFxuhNUHOMMcxtZzdGXKyNciUrz3lNHlN8k8fzaAArxaW5wEBXCos1SEBYsKRiaoxSi%2Bl7QCjIqyMym9R7SXkpaA%2BvQJLAyftffETVtKv25EfcBgDEg2UZm2Jy64PKhEiOcRU4VorxWSuANK2V8rFVWEsOhVVRA9WauONqmNcQpLNgNYGrQJqDFJh0pIWJCR7UeodB0d15j9Bet4MM0CXjBW8D9bYANRqaMIY4GYJDQq3HUY0aQWpkUsjwqAA)), mostly because `int i, cursor` are narrower than pointer-width.  The "safe" version that redoes indexing from the start of the struct does more indexing work in asm, not using the `msg+offsetof(symbol)` pointer that it was already using as the base register in the loop.

```
# original version, with UB if `i` goes past the buffer.
# gcc11.2 -O2 -march=haswell.  -O3 fully unrolls into a chain of copy/branch

      ... partially peeled first iteration
.L3:                                      # do{
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbx+8+rax], dl   # store into msg->symbol[i]
        movsx   rdi, eax                   # not read inside the loop
        lea     ecx, [r8+rax]
        inc     rax
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR buffer[rsi+1+rax]  # load from buffer
        cmp     dl, 44
        jne     .L3                       # }while(buffer[cursor+i] != ',')
## End of copy-and-search loop.  
# Loops are identical up to this point except for MOVSX here vs. MOV in the no-UB version.
        movsx   rcx, ecx       # just redo sign extension of this calculation that was done repeatedly inside the loop just for this, apparently.
.L2:
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbx+9+rdi], 10   # store a newline
        mov     eax, 1                     # set up for next loop
```

```
# offsetof version, without UB

  # same loop, but with RDI and RSI usage switched.
  # And with    mov  esi, eax  zero extension instead of  movsx rdi, eax  sign extension
        cmp     dl, 44
        jne     .L3                       # }while(buffer[cursor+i] != ',')

        add     esi, 9              # offsetof(TradeMsg, symbol)
        movsx   rcx, ecx            # more stuff getting sign extended.
        movsx   rsi, esi            # including something used in the newline store
.L2:
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbx+rsi], 10
        mov     eax, 1                  # set up for next loop
```

The RCX calculation seems to just be for use by the next loop, setting sale_conditions.

BTW, the copy-and-search loop is like strcpy but with a `','` terminator.  Unfortunately gcc/clang don't know how to optimize that; they compile to a slow byte-at-a-time loop, not e.g. an AVX512BW masked store using `mask-1` from a `vec == set1_epi8(',')` compare, to get a mask selecting the bytes-before-`','` instead of the comma element.  (Probably needs a bithack to isolate that lowest-set-bit as the only set bit, though, unless it's safe to always copy 16 or 17 bytes separate from finding the `','` position, which could be done efficiently without masked stores or branching.)

---

Another option might be a union between a `char[21]` and `struct{ char sym[17], sale[4];}`, if you use a C++ implementation that allows C99-style union type-punning.  (It's a GNU extension, and also supported by MSVC, but not necessarily literally every x86 compiler.)

---

Also, style-wise, shadowing `int i = 0;` with `for( int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++ )` is poor style.  Pick a different var name for that loop, like `j`.  (Or if there is anything meaningful, a better name for `i` which has to survive across multiple loops.)

Comment: He is talking about that particular case. I couls setup page guards and protected memory but it does not apply here.

Answer (score 2):

In a few cases:

1. When variable guard is set up: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html
2. In a C++ interpreter (yes they exist): https://root.cern/cling/

Answer (score 2):

Your symbol has a size of 17 Yet, you are trying to assign a value to the 18th index a.symbol[17] = '\0';

Remember your index value starts off at 0 not 1.

So you have two places that can go wrong. i can equal 17 which will cause an error and that last line I showed above will cause an error.

Comment: Yes I'm aware that I'm accessing the array out-of-range. But assuming it accesses symbol[17] exactly, then it's still inside the struct. And the data at symbol[17] will be assigned later. What kind of code generation can make everything else go wrong?

Comment: For added information you since I see someone else already answered.
You might want to google struct reordering and standard layout
and related topics. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout